# Import script from another folder without knowing the precise path

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, python-import

I have two files F1.py and F2.py with the following structure:

```
                      |-----F2.py
                      |
             |-----Folder2
             |
[...]-----Folder1
             |
             |-----F1.py
```

F1.py simply executes F2.py as if an app, but F2.py need variable from F1.py to run, so how am i supposed to do it ?

F2 is it's own separate app, for exemple a timer, while F1 is a launcher.
F1 automatically checks for all .py files in Folder2 and creates button for each of them so you can run them.

I've tried doing `from Folder1.F1 import var1, var2` but it just runs F1. Also, since the data I need is created during the run of the app and dependant on user input, I need to get the data *while* F1.py runs.

Also, I don't know what comes before Folder1 so there's that.

Comment: This is too vague to be answered, but sounds a lot like a circular dependency. If `F1` contains `import F2` then `F2` cannot `import F1`. The usual solution is to refactor `F2` so that `F1` can provide the values it needs access to when calling it. Or maybe move the shared code to `F3` so that both `F1` and `F2` can `import F3`

Comment: F1 doesn't `import F2` instead it does os.startfile('F2')

Comment: maybe pass vars as arguments inseatd of import?

Comment: Running the other Python script as a separate process is a _hugely_ different question than the one you seemed to be asking. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your folder structure like this:

```
folder1/
|-- py1.py
|-- folder2/
|   |-- py2.py
```

In **py1.py** I have the following code:

```
text = 'Hello World!'
```

In **py2.py** I have this code:

```
import sys
import os

# Get the path of the parent directory (project_folder)
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.append(parent_dir)

from py1 import text

print(text)
```

This is the output when I execute py2.py:

```
Hello World!
```

I hope this works for you!